# Why can't Emacs find counsel and swiper, even though they (and Ivy) seem installed, and Ivy working?

Tags: package, ivy, counsel, swiper

Why can't Emacs find `counsel` and `swiper`, even though they (as well as `ivy`) seem installed, and moreover Ivy mode is enabled, and seems to be working?

This is what I get when I try the following:

```
(package-installed-p 'ivy)
t

(package-installed-p 'counsel)
t

(package-installed-p 'swiper)
t
```

And I can also see the version information for Ivy:

```
(pkg-info-version-info 'ivy)
"0.11.0 (package: 20190412.840)"
```

But when I try to get version information for `counsel`, I get an error:

```
(pkg-info-version-info 'counsel)

Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Can’t find library counsel")
  signal(error ("Can’t find library counsel"))
  error("Can't find library %s" "counsel")
  find-library-name("counsel")
  pkg-info-library-source(counsel)
  pkg-info-library-version(counsel)
  pkg-info-version-info(counsel)
  eval((pkg-info-version-info 'counsel) nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-print-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-print-last-sexp)
```

Interestingly enough, if I visit the the packages list, `counsel` is listed as installed and I can get the following details:

```
counsel is an installed package.

     Status: Installed in ‘counsel-20190414.1926/’ (unsigned).
    Version: 20190414.1926
     Commit: 0e62f0d1f61b825ca5eb4b55e47ecb37b3e2834e
    Summary: Various completion functions using Ivy
   Requires: emacs-24.3, swiper-0.11.0
Required by: counsel-tramp-20190125.751
   Homepage: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper
   Keywords: convenience matching tools 
Other versions: 20190414.1926 (melpa).
```

My Emacs version is:

```
"GNU Emacs 27.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32)
 of 2018-06-19"
```

and I'm encountering this issue on MS Windows 10 (version 1607).

Comment: I can confirm that with same counsel version and GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) on archlinux I do get counsel version, if that's any reassurance...

Comment: Is it actually a case of Emacs not finding it? As far as I'm aware the function/command you're using there (pkg-info-version-info) is from [pkg-info.el](https://github.com/lunaryorn/pkg-info.el), which (as of 26.2 at least) isn't part of GNU Emacs.

Comment: @davep you are correct, pkg-info isn't part of Emacs, I've installed it as a package. As can be seen in my answer below, `package-initialize` solved my problem. But, it's still a mystery to me why `ivy` was working whereas `counsel` and `swiper` didn't. If it's a matter of me having to explicitly initialize, then why was `ivy` working without that. Hence my confusion.

Comment: @EmreSevinç it is curious. It might be an idea to raise the issue with the package author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following to my `.emacs` seems to solve the problem:

```
(package-initialize)
```

But I'm a little bit confused, because [41.1 Packaging Basics](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Packaging-Basics.html#Packaging-Basics) says that

> Whenever Emacs starts up, it automatically calls the function
>   package-initialize to load installed packages.

Moreover, I had the same version of Emacs on a Linux machine, and I'm using the same Emacs configuration there without any problems, that is, without `(package-initialize)`.